# Getting index out of range error when trying to pass a for loop through a list

Tags: python

The challenge is to compute the product of the elements in a list without using the range function.

Here is my program:

```
def prod(L):
    a = 1
    for i in L:
        a *= L[i] 
    return a
```

I am pretty sure that when I write the for loop, it should iterate through the list, but when I run this program, I get the error that index is out of range. Why is this happening? How can I change the program to make it work?

Thanks in advance for your replies!

Comment: `for i in L: print(i)` Look at that output. Try with `[0, 1, 20]` and it should be obvious why `L[i]` fails; the 3rd value tries to take the 21st (don't forget we have 0 indexing) item from a list that you can clearly see only contains 3 items. You can't take an item at position 21 from a list containing 3 items

Comment: use `a *= i`. You are iterating over the list elements.

Comment: `for i in L` gives you every *value* in `L`, not every *index* into L. Just do `a *= i`, not `a *= L[i]`.

Answer (score 3):

use i instead of L[i]

```
ml = [1,2,3]

def prod(L):
    a = 1
    for i in L:
        a *= i
    return a

prod(ml)
```

output:

```
6
```